# How to change the IP Address through user-defined variable in BASH SCRIPT?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a Bash Script to change my IP Address. I'm able to change the IP Address manually from "ifconfig" command. I am also able to change the IP Address through my script when I declare a particular chosen address as a variable.

Such as:

```
IP="000.000.0.0"
```

But it is not changing the IP Address when I'm taking it as a user-defined variable.

Such as:

```
echo "ENTER THE NEW IP ADDRESS: " && read -p ""$NEW_IP
```

or

```
echo "ENTER THE NEW IP ADDRESS: "
read -p ""$NEW_IP
```

The full code, What I wrote was:

```
INTER_FACE="wlp9s0"
echo "ENTER THE NEW IP ADDRESS  : "
read -p ""$NEW_IP

ifconfig $INTER_FACE down
ifconfig $INTER_FACE inet $NEW_IP
ifconfig $INTER_FACE up
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the read command is wrong. You have to do

```
read NEW_IP
```

instead